# Automapper mapping Powershell PSObject

Tags: powershell, automapper, psobject

What's the easiest method to map from a a PSObject returned from a PowerShell host in C#?

Example program (minus the actual mapping):

```
class SOResult
{
    public DateTime A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}

var script = "@{ A = (Get-Date); B = 'Hello World' };";

var instance = PowerShell.Create();
instance.AddScript(script);

var invokeResult = instance.Invoke();

var psObject = invokeResult.First();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best method I've found so far. The key is to access `.BaseObject` on the PSObject, this returns a Hashtable, then mapping it is fairly simple:

```
CreateMap<Hashtable, SOResult>()
    .ForMember(o => o.A, x => x.MapFrom(f => f["A"]))
    .ForMember(o => o.B, x => x.MapFrom(f => f["B"]));
```

Complete working program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Mapper.Initialize(c => c.AddProfile<SOProfile>());

    var script = "@{ A = (Get-Date); B = 'Hello World' };";

    var instance = PowerShell.Create();
    instance.AddScript(script);

    var invokeResult = instance.Invoke();

    var psObject = invokeResult.First().BaseObject;

    var soResult = Mapper.Map<SOResult>(psObject);

    Debug.Assert(soResult != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(soResult.B));
}


class SOProfile : Profile
{
    public SOProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Hashtable, SOResult>()
            .ForMember(o => o.A, x => x.MapFrom(f => f["A"]))
            .ForMember(o => o.B, x => x.MapFrom(f => f["B"]));
    }

}
```

Unfortunately if you have more than simple properties, this is becomes painful, because you need to convert the child properties from PSObject to Hashtable repeatedly.